# creating a tree view based on parent_id

Tags: elixir

I have a list of maps, and I am struggling to build an html tree which after clicking an element, shows a list of its children. What is the best way to do such thing?

For example:
We have a list of maps:
`[%Person{name: "name1", id: 1, parent_id: nil}, %Person{name: "name2", id: 2, parent_id: 1},%Person{name: "name3", id: 3, parent_id: 2}]`

I want to get something like this:

```
name1 ↓
       name2 ↓
              name 3
```

I will be grateful for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a tricky problem because if you need to traverse to the final leaf of the tree, you have to traverse the list many times (I'll let someone else tell you the exact O(n)).

However if you just need to show the immediate children as your question implies, [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) is your friend. You could write a function that accepts the list of people and the id of the parent whose children you wish to see.

For example, if you wish to find all the people at the root (where `parent_id = nil`):

```
iex> parent_id = nil 
nil
iex> Enum.filter(people, fn %{parent_id: id} -> id == parent_id end)
[%{id: 1, name: "name1", parent_id: nil}]
```

Comment: Thank's alot for help! This resolved my issue and shortened my previous code greatly!